# Opencart - Где редактировать шаблон из админки?

Tags: opencart, админка

Подскажите, где можно отредактировать футер, да и в целом блоки шаблона? Поскольку заходя в код я вижу только: `<?php echo $header; ?>` или

```
<h5 class="footer-title"><?php echo $text_information; ?></h5>
```

Где в админке искать всё это? Поиска там не вижу... 
Захожу "Design"->"Layouts" и там много различных страниц... как понять какая что именно та или иная отвечает за главную страницу? Методом "тыка? 
[image: кол-во-страниц]

Comment: до 3й версии - никак. Токмо напрямую в tpl-файлах.

Comment: в tpl файлах шаблонах я нахожу только <?php echo $text_information; ?> и похожее.

Comment: А сами страницы где редактировать?

Comment: это и есть страницы. $text_information - переменная, один из множества динамических элементов, которые поставляются контроллером в tpl-файлы. А в layouts лишь определяются(назначаются) модули на страницу + осуществляется роут(кастомно) на определённые файлы представлений(.tpl) Рекомендую вам сузить вопрос до конкретной задачи, решение которой вы пытаетесь найти. На данный момент вопрос очень общий и требует от вас набора определённых знаний.